# If ABCD is a quadrilateral in which AB || CD and AD=BC, prove that $\angle$A=$\angle$ B.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

> Q. Let ABCD be a quadrilateral in which AB || CD and AD=BC. Prove that $\angle$A=$\angle$ B.

My attempt:

Connecting BD and AC and trying to prove $ \Delta ADC \cong \Delta BCD $.

[image: Diagram]

In $ \Delta ADC \text{ and }\Delta BCD $:

$AD=BC$(given),

$DC=DC$.

---

I need to prove $ \angle ADC = \angle BCD$ in order to prove the two triangles are congruent by SAS congruency criterion. But I don't know how  $ \angle ADC = \angle BCD$ in the above problem?

Comment: What if $AD = BC$ in another way, like a parallelogram?

Comment: Proving $\angle ADC = \angle BCD$ is as difficult as proving $\angle A = \angle B$, by symmetry.

Comment: right..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop an altitude onto $AB$ from $D$ and from $C$. Since $AB\parallel DC$, the altitudes have the same length. Also $AD=BC$, so

$$\sin \angle A=\sin \angle B$$

Either $\angle A=\angle B$, or $\angle A+\angle B=180^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E\in{DC}$ such that $AE||BC$. Thus, $AECB$ is parallelogram,

which gives $AE=BC$ and from here $AE=AD$.

Thus, $\measuredangle ADE=\measuredangle AED=\measuredangle BCD$.

Now,
$$\measuredangle DAB=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle ADC=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle BCD=\measuredangle ABC$$
and we are done!

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$1)$ drop altitudes $AE$ and $BF$ onto $BC$ and prove $\Delta ADE=\Delta BCF$.

$2)$ in two right angle triangles, if two corresponding sides are equal, the third sides are also equal (why?).

Comment: Right... By RHS congruency criterion $\Delta ADE=\Delta BCF$ . But is there any property which says perpendicular distance between two parallel lines are equal?...(It can be deduced intuitively though)......So you are equating the right angle,hypotenuse and THE SIDE(THE ALTITUDE)?

Comment: for distance between parallel lines check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_between_two_straight_lines. for equality, when hypotenuses and one legs of right angle triangles are equal, then due to Pythagoras theorem, the third sides are uniquely defined and also equal.